# Listagem automática PDO e MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Boa tarde. Estou tentando fazer com que as tabelas sejam listadas automáticas, sem eu ter que por o nome do campo da mesma. Porém está apresentando erros.

```
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''));
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$result = $conn->query("SHOW TABLES");

                while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){

                    $table = $conn->query("SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM ".$row[0]);
                    $busca = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM ".$row[0]);
                    $rows = '';
                    echo '<br>';

                    while ($res = $table->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
                        echo $res[0].'<br>';    

                        while ($resS = $busca->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                            $rows = $res[0] .' - '. $resS[$res[0]].'<br>';
                            echo $rows;
                        }           
                    }               

                }
```

$res[0] está listando certo o nome dos campos:

```
idCliente
cliente_Nome
cliente_Cpf
cliente_Endereco
cliente_Numero
cliente_Bairro
cliente_Cidade
cliente_Estado
```

Porém quando tento usar os dados de cada tabela, retornados pelo $resS, não apresenta os valores inseridos, ou quando apresenta fica somente o id ou duplicados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

José, consegui fazer algo aqui.
Pelo que entendi, faltou percorrer os dados no $resS.
Veja o código que fiz abaixo e veja se lhe atende:

```
$result = $conn->query("SHOW TABLES");

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
    $table = $conn->query("SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM " . $row[0]);
    $busca = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM " . $row[0]);
    $rows = '';

    while($res = $table->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
       while ($resS = $busca->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
          foreach ($resS as $chv => $vlr){
             echo $chv . ' - ' . $vlr . '<br>';
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Deu certo amigo. Isso tudo que estou fazendo é para tentar verificar dois bancos de dados e após a comparação fazer uma sincronização. Tens uma base além disso para eu seguir?

Comment: Olha, se eu fosse fazer algo parecido, eu iria ler os registros de um banco e pegar alguns campos-chave para ver se esses campos existem no outro banco. Por exemplo em um cadastro de clientes, eu pegaria o campo CPF para fazer essa comparação. Se não existir, gravar lá. Acredito que alguém com mais experiência já tenha passado por isso.

Comment: Só uma coisa, Luis, se a solução lhe atendeu, por favor, marque a resposta como Resolvida. Obrigado!

Comment: Vou tentar, pois tem um cliente que quer meu sistema tanto local quanto web. Dai não achei nenhum biblioteca que faça essa sincronização. To meio que desesperado. Já tentei por mysqldump, porém não deu certo. Se soubre de algo, pff. Ficaria eternamente grato!! Vlw desde já.

Comment: Abra uma pergunta sobre isso aqui, Luis. Tem muita gente experiente que provavelmente pode te ajudar. Sincronização de banco de dados é algo interessante. Porém, será que após o fim da sincronização, seria mais adequado ambos os sistemas acessar apenas um banco?

Comment: Sim, eu tinha feito assim, os dois acessavam o web, porém o cliente tem medo de que se faltar internet e tal.

Comment: Entendi... uma sugestão (sou leigo...) que eu dou seria a cada gravação local e na web, se der problema na gravação da web cria algum "flag", alguma coisa falando que deverá ser feita a sincronização e daí deixaria um serviço a ser executado de madrugada, por exemplo, para realizar essa sincronização caso o "flag" estiver criado. Aí estaria garantindo que sempre que der algum problema, em um certo momento irá entrar a sincronização.

Comment: Ta ok. Obrigado. Vamos tentar.